# how to get all data without paging in jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

I work with jqGrid 4.6.0, ASP.Net MVC5, anything well don. But i have one problem bellow.
When i remove paging from page. I want load all data for jqGrid without paging. But data has just only displayed 20 record in jqGrid page. Although return data from server 36 record.

My JQGrid:

```
var Pattern_Grid = $("#Pattern_Grid");
    Pattern_Grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        height: 250,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        width: null,
        rownumbers: true,
        multiselect: true,
        pgbuttons: false,

        viewrecords: false,
        pgtext: "",
        pginput: false,
        //==========================================
        url: "/CusURL/GetBom",
        caption: "Patterns Linking",
        postData: {
            styleCode: styleCode, size: styleSize, serial: styleColorSerial, revNo: revNo
        },
        //mtype: 'POST',
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "MainItemCode", index: "MainItemCode",
                label: arrPatternCollName.MainItemCode,
                search: false, sort: false
            },
            {
                name: "ItemCode", index: "ItemCode",
                label: arrPatternCollName.ItemCode,
                search: false, sort: false
            },
            {
                name: "ItemName", index: "ItemName",
                label: arrPatternCollName.ItemName,
                search: false, sort: false
            },
            {
                name: "ItemColorWays", index: "ItemColorWays",
                label: arrPatternCollName.MainItemColorSerial
            },
            { name: "StyleColorSerial", index: "StyleColorSerial", hidden: false },
            { name: "UnitConSumTion", index: "UnitConSumTion", hidden: false },
            { name: "Consumpunit", index: "Consumpunit", hidden: false },
            { name: "Qty", index: "Qty", hidden: false },
            { name: "CurrCode", index: "CurrCode", hidden: false },
            { name: "RegistryDate", index: "RegistryDate", hidden: false },

            { name: "StyleCode", index: "StyleCode", hidden: true },
            { name: "StyleSize", index: "StyleSize", hidden: true },
            { name: "ItemColorSerial", index: "ItemColorSerial", hidden: true },
            { name: "RevNo", index: "RevNo", hidden: true },
            { name: "MainItemColorSerial", index: "MainItemColorSerial", hidden: true },
            { name: "PatternCode", index: "PatternCode", hidden: true }
    });
```

My data return more than 36 record data has just only displays 20 record in jqGrid page:
 url: "/CusURL/GetBom",

```
public JsonResult GetBom(string styleCode, string styleSize, string styleColorSerial, string revNo)
        {
            try
            {
                var bom = _bom.GetBom(styleCode, styleSize, styleColorSerial, revNo);
                return Json(bom.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new List<Bomt>().ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to to display all data in jqGrid without paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rowNum default value is set to 20

you can set rowNum = 10000 or  use 'jsonp' result for load all of datas with lazy load.